# g++ breaking change in std::filesystem::last_write_time

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

With recent OS upgrade I noticed that small part of my code stopped compiling - it seems the reason is switching from `g++-8` to `g++-9`.

This code is compiling alright on `g++ 8.3.0` (verified this using `gcc:8.3` image from Dockerhub)

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::filesystem::last_write_time("test", std::chrono::system_clock::now() - 5min);
}
```

On `g++ 9.1.0` it fails with:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:8:69: error: no matching function for call to 'last_write_time(const char [5], std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >)'
    8 |  fs::last_write_time("test", std::chrono::system_clock::now() - 5min);
      |                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/filesystem:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:243:19: note: candidate: 'std::filesystem::file_time_type std::filesystem::last_write_time(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)'
  243 |   file_time_type  last_write_time(const path& __p);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:243:19: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:244:19: note: candidate: 'std::filesystem::file_time_type std::filesystem::last_write_time(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&, std::error_code&)'
  244 |   file_time_type  last_write_time(const path& __p, error_code& __ec) noexcept;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/filesystem:36,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_fwd.h:362:47: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >' to 'std::error_code&'
  362 |   file_time_type last_write_time(const path&, error_code&) noexcept;
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/filesystem:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:245:8: note: candidate: 'void std::filesystem::last_write_time(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&, std::filesystem::file_time_type)'
  245 |   void last_write_time(const path& __p, file_time_type __new_time);
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:245:56: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock,[...]>' to 'time_point<std::filesystem::__file_clock,[...]>'
  245 |   void last_write_time(const path& __p, file_time_type __new_time);
      |                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:246:8: note: candidate: 'void std::filesystem::last_write_time(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&, std::filesystem::file_time_type, std::error_code&)'
  246 |   void last_write_time(const path& __p, file_time_type __new_time,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/fs_ops.h:246:8: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Compile command: `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -lstdc++-fs` (even though linking `stdc++-fs` is unnecessary on since `g++9`)

My question is - what is the idiomatic use of this function the way I intended? Namely changing the last write time of a file to five minutes ago.

I understand I used this in somehow non-idiomatic way if a breaking change was introduced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out by @LightnessRacesinOrbit in their answer the [`std::filesystem::file_time_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type) that `last_write_time` takes uses an unspecified `time_point` type.  This means it is completely legal for this to break moving from one compiler to another or even versions of the same compiler.

What you can do though is get the clock that the implementation uses, and use that yourself.  [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) was built to take the clock type that creates it as a template parameter, and it surfaces a public `clock` type that represents that.  So to portably get the clock, and call `now` on it you can use

```
std::filesystem::last_write_time("test", std::filesystem::file_time_type::clock::now() - 5min);
//                                       ^ give me whatever clock you use and call now on it
```

Answer (score 4):

This is touched on by [cppreference.com's example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time).

Your giving a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>` to [`std::file_time_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type) was never portable; it just happened to work on your previous toolchain. That wasn't really your fault: you were unavoidably relying on implementation details.

C++20 has introduced a portable alternative, so you'd do:

```
std::filesystem::last_write_time("test", std::chrono::file_clock::now() - 5min);
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

… i.e. use `file_clock`, rather than just hoping that the alternative is convertible to whatever implementation-defined clock is used by your toolchain.

Whether that's supported in GCC 9 I couldn't say for sure, though [it doesn't look like it](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-9/changes.html). If there's a workaround, I'm not aware of one (which is why the C++20 change was made).

[This problem affects other people on other toolchains](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251213/stdfilesystemfile-time-type-does-not-allow-easy-co.html), too.

Comment: This was due to [P0355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r3.html).

Comment: @Barry The improved behaviour was added by that proposal yes but, in its absence, the actual problem is due to the silly prior specification in concert with pure chance and toolchain updates!

Comment: Yeah don't disagree, just adding info. Also gcc didn't claim to be C++17 feature complete in 8 yet, so ABI changes are still possible.